# FBJS AJAX.post is not working after permissions dialog

Tags: ajax, flash, actionscript-3, facebook, fbjs

I have problems with facebook application based on flash which communicate with PHP using FBJS-bridge. When someone use the application for the first time, he/she is asked for various permissions. After that, flash contact PHP with ajax but request is never sent. When you refresh page, everything is working without any problems.
If you remove the application on privacy settings, refresh the page and try again - same bug happens. If you allow application, refresh page, in other tab remove application and start application in previous tab - user is asked for permissions but everything is working after allowing application.

This is FBJS code

```
function openPermissions(){
    Facebook.showPermissionDialog(/*permissions string*/, permissionOnDone);
}
function permissionOnDone(perms){
    if (!perms) {
        document.getElementById("indexswf").callSWF('noallow');
    } else {
        document.getElementById("indexswf").callSWF('allow');
    }
}

function ajaxCall(url,parameters){
    var params = {};
    for(var i=0;i<parameters.length;i+=2){
        params[parameters[i]]=parameters[i+1];
    }

    ajax = new Ajax();
    ajax.requireLogin = true;
    ajax.responseType = Ajax.RAW;
    ajax.ondone = function(data){
        document.getElementById("indexswf").callSWF('parseAjax', data);
    }

    ajax.post('http://the.url.to/the_real_server/not_to_the_fb_url/'+url,params);
}
```

openPermissions is called to display permission dialog, and on allow flash function allow() is called. In flash, allow() calls JS function ajaxCall(), which should make ajax request. But, ajax.post never sends request. I know that for sure, because flash function parseAjax was never called and also debugging tools in browsers are not showing any ajax requests. URL and parameters are same as when it is working. No flash or JS errors are detected...
Anyone have idea what is wrong here? Maybe facebook bug again since this was all working few days ago...

Comment: fbjs will be deprecated in March http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462 (last paragraph) so it's better to build iframe app's

Comment: It looks like ajax.requireLogin = true was making the problem all the time. I set it to false and it works now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax.requireLogin = true should be set to false for some reason